Google Console Pre-launch report: java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'End of String'
Edit (10.10.2024): Just for information. Google seems to have now resolved the problem itself.
In all my revisions, this type of error is no longer displayed in the Google Play Console pre-launch report, and it has also been removed retroactively everywhere.
I'm currently fighting against the Play Console's pre-launch reports.
All of my latest app updates have this error.
Can I assume that this error occurs in an external component (com.google.android.markup) and is not directly related to my app? The affected app does not have any corresponding bug reports in public live operation.
According to the pre-launch report, only this test device is affected:
google Pixel 6, 1080x2400, Android 12 (SDK 31), 8,192 MB, arm64-v8a, de_DE
Here ist the bug report:
00-00 00:00:00.000     0     0 ? (none)  : --------- beginning of crash
07-02 02:49:03.636 21961 21961 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-02 02:49:03.636 21961 21961 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.google.android.markup, PID: 21961
07-02 02:49:03.636 21961 21961 E AndroidRuntime: java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'End of String'
07-02 02:49:03.636 21961 21961 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifierParser.peek(Formatter.java:2642)
07-02 02:49:03.636 21961 21961 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifierParser.<init>(Formatter.java:2603)
07-02 02:49:03.636 21961 21961 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2558)
07-02 02:49:03.636 21961 21961 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2505)
07-02 02:49:03.636 21961 21961 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2459)
07-02 02:49:03.636 21961 21961 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2911)
07-02 02:49:03.636 21961 21961 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:562)
07-02 02:49:03.636 21961 21961 E AndroidRuntime:    at ui.u(PG:14)
07-02 02:49:03.636 21961 21961 E AndroidRuntime:    at ui.x(PG:8)
07-02 02:49:03.636 21961 21961 E AndroidRuntime:    at ui.k(PG:11)
07-02 02:49:03.636 21961 21961 E AndroidRuntime:    at uh.a(PG:1)
07-02 02:49:03.636 21961 21961 E AndroidRuntime:    at fw.createAccessibilityNodeInfo(PG:1)
07-02 02:49:03.636 21961 21961 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.populateAccessibilityNodeInfoForView(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:403)
07-02 02:49:03.636 21961 21961 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.findAccessibilityNodeInfoByAccessibilityIdUiThread(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:358)
07-02 02:49:03.636 21961 21961 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.access$500(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:74)
07-02 02:49:03.636 21961 21961 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$PrivateHandler.handleMessage(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1547)
07-02 02:49:03.636 21961 21961 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
07-02 02:49:03.636 21961 21961 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
07-02 02:49:03.636 21961 21961 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
07-02 02:49:03.636 21961 21961 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
07-02 02:49:03.636 21961 21961 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-02 02:49:03.636 21961 21961 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
07-02 02:49:03.636 21961 21961 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)

I have checked my code several times, all string operations (format strings like %s, %d, etc. seem to be OK.
PS: I'm a full-time Windows software developer and only do Android on the side respectively I'm in the process of getting more into touch with Android in more detail. That works quite well, but I'm reaching my limits with this question.
It would be nice if someone could shed some light on this question for me. Thank you in advance.
